# Mongoose model is an empty object inside post hook of another model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My project has 2 models referring to one another. When the instances of one model are removed, `remove()` method will hook another model to remove the dependencies.

**photo.model.js**

```
const Album = require('./album');
       .
       .
// post hook of photo.remove()
schema.post('remove', (photo, next) => {

  console.log(Album);  // return empty obj {}

  Album.findById(photo._album, (error, album) => {
        // find album and remove photo
    });
});
```

Album model inside remove hook return empty object. I found the fix by moving require statement inside the hook.

```
schema.post('remove', (photo, next) => {
  const Album = require('./album');
  Album.findById(photo._album, (error, album) => {
        // find album and remove photo
    });
});
```

But the fix looks ugly to me and my guess is every time `photo.remove()` is called `require` statement is called.

---

**Question:**

- Is my guess above about "`require` getting called every time `photo.remove()` is called" correct?
- Why can't I place the `require` outside the hook and having same behavior as inside?
- Is there anyway I can place `require` outside the hook and get the same behavior as placing it inside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you have a cyclic dependency, where `photo.model.js` requires `album.js` which requires `photo.model.js`, ...

To work around that, you can use this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

schema.post('remove', (photo, next) => {
  mongoose.model('Album').findById(photo._album, (error, album) => {
    // find album and remove photo
  });
});
```

Comment: Cyclic dependency indeed. When I comment out `require('photo.model')` in `Album.js` to break the cycle, problem solved. Your solution works perfectly and clean. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @robertklep for this answer! I could not understand what was wrong at all. I knew that it was a cycle. This answer helped me work around it! Also, thanks to NERDYLIZARD for asking this question 4 years back! :)